# "of" with measurement expressions

Tags: prepositions, measure-expressions

I'd like to know whether "of" is properly used in the following sentences:

> 1. John bought a rope **of** between 10 and 20 cm.
> 2. John bought a rope between 10 and 20 cm.
> 3. John bought a rope **of** between 10 and 20 cm in length.
> 4. John bought a rope between 10 and 20 cm in length.
> 5. John bought a rope **of** 10–20 cm.
> 6. John bought a rope 10–20 cm.
> 7. John bought a rope **of** 10–20 cm in length.
> 8. John bought a rope 10–20 cm in length.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is idiomatic to use **of** in such expressions.

> A distance of ten or twenty miles.
>
> A journey of ten or twenty miles.
>
> A speed of between 80 and 90 miles per hour.
>
> A ladder of 30 feet.
>
> He placed the billet or steel in a furnace of over 1000 degrees.

When using **of** there is no need to include the prepositional phrase expressing the nature of the measurement:

> You will need a ladder 30 feet *in length*.

and it sounds a little "off" to my ear to include the prepositional phrase when using **of**:

> A ladder *of* 30 feet *in length*.

but I wouldn't go so far as to say it was unidiomatic.

But **of** is required if you omit that prepositional phrase:

> You will need a ladder 30 feet. <sup>unidiomatic</sup>
>
> You will need a ladder of 30 feet.

Comment: Do you mean #2 and #6 of the OP are unidiomatic?

Comment: The word **between** and the hyphenated measurement **20-30** soften the jarring effect somewhat.  But I would consider this marginal: *John bought a rope 20cm*.  My ear is waiting for *long* or *in length*.

Comment: As always, this is based on my sense  of how people use these phrases. I'm not being prescriptive.  But you could easily hear this in a hardware store: *I need a strand of wire ... {reflective pause} 20-30 cm* or  *I need a strand of wire, oh...some 20-30cm* or *I need a strand of wire ... um...let's say 20-30 cm*.   The less precise the statement, the more vague it is, the more hesitant the speaker in delivering it, the fewer demands there are upon it to be "well formed".  The reflective pause and the words **some** and **let's say** fulfill the function of **of**.

Comment: As a corollary to my comment above, your barebones presentation of phrases in a vacuum is NOT a good way to ask many of the questions you ask, since small things often make major differences.  Always supply a context for these utterances (are you writing an ad, a formal essay, a letter to the editor, a journal article, whatever) and a full sentence that dramatizes the situation concretely.

Comment: Suppose I were writing a school essay. Would #1 be natural?  As in many other cases, I've received mixed responses to the sentences; someone says only #8 comes close to being correct (albeit with "long" in place of "in length"), and another says he'd only use #4 (albeit, again, with "long" in place of "in length").